# How can I sent an payment invoice to my client email using node.js

Tags: stripe-payments, nodemailer, automatic-updates

Now I want to make an eCommerce website. In this website, I want to implement a feature like when a client or user buy something from my website and they also pay with any payment gateway (In case I use Stripe payment gateway) After completing payment, I want to send an automatic order completion invoice to my client email with product name, quantity, subtotal, total and so on. That means we receive our client order and payment.

**
Advanced Thank's
Ariful Islam JR.
MERN Stack Developer**

I have no idea about this problem to get a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really want is a receipt to be sent to your customer on payment completion. There's a couple ways to achieve this. Assuming you want the customer to pay on your website and not on a Stripe-hosted page, then you could use [the accept a payment guide with a custom flow](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements) and [add a receipt email when creating the PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-receipt_email). This would email your customer a receipt on successful payment completion. You could also achieve this with [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout) if you want a Stripe-hosted payment page by [enabling email receipts in your settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/emails).